# What is the difference between \usepackage{mcode} and \usepackage{listings} for MATLAB codes?

Tags: listings, matlab

I know there is available in the MATLAB Central File Exchange site the `mcode.sty` package, which allows to put MATLAB codes into TeX files.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package

However, there is also available in LaTeX a package called `listings.sty`, which I guess does pretty much the same thing.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings

What is the difference between them? Are there any advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 13):

`mcode` is customized to write matlab codes. It too uses `listings` for this job. Hence it is like a ready made shirt, you just wear it. `listings` is like cloth from which you have to stitch the shirt yourself. It is a general package for typesetting codes. You have to define the setting for matlab yourself and use it.

Hence the bottom line is, with `mcode` you have predefined settings for matlab code while with `listings` you have to define them. It is `listings` that is in action with both packages.

PS: There is [`matlab-prettifier`](http://ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) by jubobs, that is recent and has much more than `mcode` to offer. I advice to try it for typesetting matlab codes.