# `.cls` and `.sty` files merging to create an appendix

Tags: pdftex, document-classes

I have a `.tex` file, actually it is from a certain layout of my university, and it comes with a `.cls` file of its own. And now I have to create an appendix section contains only some Matlab codes. I have found an example latex code for Matlab code and as I guessed there is a `.sty` file with it. Unfortunately as they have different document class, I could not merge them  together. For example, in the `.sty` file the coder has defined `\lstdefinelanguage{matlabfloz}`, and in my main`.tex` file coud not recognize it.

Here is my question, do I have to define that language in the `.cls` file? Or there is some easier way without doing that?

(I tried to use `\inputpdf` command, I do not have any error message afterwards, but it does not appear in compiled pdf which is I did not understand.)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode} 
\appendix 
\begin{document} 
\begin{lstlisting} 
for i = 1:3 
  if i >= 5 && a ~= b % literate programming replacement disp('cool'); % comment with some §\mcommentfont\LaTeX in it: $\mcommentfont\pi x^2$§ end [:,ind] = max(vec); 
  x_last = x(1,end) - 1; 
  v(end); 
  really really long really really long really really long really really long really really long line % blaaaaaaaa ylabel('Voltage (µV)'); 
end 
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not recommend to change in the `.cls`-file. If I understand right your proiblem is that the command `lstdefinelanguage` is not defined. Have you included the `listings`package (`\usepackage{listings}`) beforte you use it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I have included `listings` package. I guess the problem is `mcode` package. It gives an error such as "Package Listings Error: language matlabfloz undefined."  However when I open `mcode.sty` file, I see a line `\lstdefinelanguage{matlabfloz}` in it.`mcode.sty` is normally does not exist in MiKTex installation files, so I added it myself manually.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214617/95544

Comment: This is the code that I found for implementing the MATLAB codes. And it works errorless when I compile it seperately. However I need to add appendix in my own `thesis.tex` file which is started `\documentclass[chaparabic,ceng,ms,12pt,oneandhalf]{metu}`. here the `{metu}` stands for the `{metu}.cls` (I guess). I think I should change or add somethings in that `{metu}.cls` file. @David Carlisle

Comment: please don't add example code in comments, as you see it dies not really work, you can edit the question to add an example in a code block. I see no reason why you would need to change a class file.

Comment: so what happens if you take the article class example in your comment and replace `\documentclass{article}` by `\documentclass[chaparabic,ceng,ms,12pt,oneandhalf]{metu}` does it work or do you get an error? If you get an error , show the error in the question...

Comment: I am sorry I have added it in my question part. What you say is also does not work, I get then some other errors regarding my other chapters. Maybe I must add `\documentclass[chaparabic,ceng,ms,12pt,oneandhalf,something here]{metu}` But nothing works. I thnk I should edit `metu.cls` but I do not know how.

Comment: please fix the example and put the linebreaks back, there is no chance to correctly parse the matlab comments with it all on one line. If you provide no example and do not show the _exact_ error message form the log, it isn't really possible to help. It would be very surprising if you have to edit the class file, but it is not in the standard tex distribution and you have given no link to it so no one can help you edit that with the information you have given so far